# How do I add a Stream operation parameter to my function?

Tags: methods, java-8, java-stream

I have a function that performs some stream operations (a filter, in particular) on a `List`.

```
public List<String> getAndFilterNames(List<Person> people, Predicate<Person> nameFilter){
  List<String> allNames = people.stream()
    .map(person -> person.getName())
    .filter(nameFilter)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
  return allNames;
}
```

I want to be able to pass an intermediate stream operation (`filter`, `distinct`, etc.) and have my function perform that operation before running the terminal operation. Something like:

```
public List<String> getAndProcessNames(List<Person> people, <intermediate stream operation>){
  List<String> allNames = people.stream()
    .map(person -> person.getName())
    // perform <intermediate stream operation> here
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
  return allNames;
}
```

Though, with my current level of experience, it seems impossible. Some intermediate operations have a parameter (like `filter`), and others don't (like `distinct`), so I can't set up a single parameter type that will handle all cases...I suppose I could create a couple of signatures though, using `Function` and `Supplier`.

Even then, the functional interface that the functions with parameters require varies...`filter` takes a `Predicate`, `map` takes a `Function`, and from what I understand, there is no way to denote a generic functional interface. Is that correct? There is no actual common class or interface that they all draw from.

So, in the end, it seems that my best bet is to just `map` and `collect` and then run my desired stream operation in a case-by-case basis, like:

```
public List<String> getNames(List<Person> people){
  List<String> allNames = people.stream()
    .map(person -> person.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
  return allNames;
}

List<Person> employees = // a bunch of people
List<String> employeeNames = getNames(employees);
employeeNames = employeeNames.stream(). // desired operations
```

**EDIT**: Or, per @Holger:

```
public Stream<String> getNamesStream(List<Person> people){
  Stream<String> namesStream = people.stream()
    .map(person -> person.getName());
  return namesStream;
}

List<Person> employees = // a bunch of people
Stream<String> employeeNamesStream = getNamesStream(employees);
employeeNamesStream(). // desired operations
```

Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want is a function from `Stream` to `Stream`.  For example:

```
public List<String> processNames(Function<Stream<String>, Stream<String>> f) {
    return f.apply(people.stream().map(Person::getName))
            .collect(toList());
}
```

Then invoke like:

```
List<String> filteredNames = processNames(s -> s.filter(n -> n.startsWith("A")));
```

Comment: So then, the only “advantage” is that the caller is forced into receiving a collected `List` instead of being allowed to chain its own terminal operation. And the function is not allowed to map to something other than `String`. I’d call that an anti-pattern, caused by a collection-centric view. The alternative, just returning the stream to allow arbitrary subsequent operations should be mentioned.

Comment: The OP wanted to know if there was any way to pass a "stream operation" as data.  The idiom of "pass a unary operator instead" isn't obvious at first, and is sometimes useful.  Whether it is worthwhile in this case or not is irrelevant (and nitpicking on whether this is the right place to apply it seems like deliberately missing the point).  The point here is that there is a sensible upleveling of the request from "pass a stream operation" to "pass a way to modify a stream" that is a useful tool to have in your toolbox, and which clearly hadn't occurred yet to the OP (and others).

Comment: I’m not objecting against telling this solution, I’m just suggesting telling also the other solution that apparently hadn't occurred yet to the OP either and might solve the actual problem, as this very much looks like an xy-problem.

Comment: @BrianGoetz This is great; thank you. Even if I knew how to classify that `Function<Stream<String>, Stream<String>>`, I had no idea what I would do with it from there. Definitely adds to my toolbox.

Comment: @Holger I see where you're coming from, though the contract of my function is to always return a `List<String>`. The idea of returning the stream itself hadn't occurred to me; I see that it could be useful for something else in the future.

Comment: @Holger A nod to your thoughts at the end of the original question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. There's no common base interface that intermediate operations would extend, but there should not be one too because of the different operations that they actually perform.

You *could* create some methods that you could chain those calls:

```
private static <T> Stream<T> applyPredicates(Stream<T> input, List<Predicate<T>> predicates) {
    Stream<T> result = Stream.concat(input, Stream.empty());
    for (Predicate<T> pred : predicates) {
          result = result.filter(pred);
    }
    return result;
}

/**
  * this could be modified to accept more then one parameters
  */
private static <T, R> Stream<R> applyFunction(Stream<T> input, Function<T, R> function) {
     return input.map(function);
}
```

And then for example :

```
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", null, "three");

  Predicate<String> p1 = t -> t != null;
  Predicate<String> p2 = t -> t.startsWith("t");

  applyFunction(applyPredicates(list.stream(), Arrays.asList(p1, p2)), String::length)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Notice that applyFunctions would have to be overloaded to take numerous Functions as input parameters, since each map operation might change the stream from T to R and then to Y and so on.

Comment: It was a good start =) Hopefully we both learned something here